# Currently reordering item not rebuilt in ReorderableListView

Tags: flutter

I have a list of widgets wrapped in a `ReorderableList` that are pretty huge, and so I wish to achieve the effect of "collapsing" certain parts of the widget while the reordering is happening.

**Here's what I have achieved so far:**

```
return ReorderableListView(
        onReorderEnd: (index) {
           setState(() {
                      shouldCollapse = true;
                    });
        },
        onReorderStart: (index) {
           setState(() {
                      shouldCollapse = true;
                    });
        },
        onReorder: (int oldIndex, int newIndex) async {
           // Some code for reodering
        },
        children: [
          BigWidget(shouldCollapse:shouldCollapse);
        ],
      );
```

**However, this does not fully achieve the intended effect.**

=> The item that's being reordered does not collapse

**Questions:**

1. May I ask why is this side effect happening?
2. May I ask if there are any foreseeable consequences of modifying the "parameters" passed to the reorderable items while reordering is happening?
3. May I ask if there's a better way to modify the list (rebuilding it) whilst the reordering is happening?

EDIT: Here is the current effect:

[image: demo]

Code for BigWidget

```
class BigWidget extends ConsumerWidget {
  final bool shouldCollapse;

  BigWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.shouldCollapse,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return Card(
      elevation: 0,
      child: 
         if (shouldCollapse == false)
             // Display logic for the hidden items
         //Rest of widget
    );
  }
}
```

**Update 2:**

[image: Here!]

**Dartpad example:** (fixed link)

[demo](https://dartpad.dev/?id=223dd1bb9885ae95a46a05a456b69fe8)

Comment: Can you post a small gif of what’s the fault

Comment: @SankethB.K hey thanks for the response, I have made an edit

Comment: Can you post the code of BigWidget, i want to see how are you using the value of shouldCollapse

Comment: @SankethB.K Hey! I've updated the question with a stripped-down version of the code for relevance, hope it helps!

Comment: Initially all widgets are in non-collapsed state. But as soon as you start reordering they are in collapsed state, am i right?

Comment: Yes thats right @SankethB.K

Answer (score 1):

I went through the source code of `ReorderableList` turns out the re-ordering widget is not rebuilt by default during the process of re-ordering.

If you want it to be rebuilt or animationed, use the proxyDecorator callback.

```
ReorderableList(
    ...
    proxyDecorator: (child, index, animation) {
      return BigWidget(shouldCollapse: true);

},)
```

Let me know if this works

Comment: Hey sorry just coming back to this question again, realize that the BigWidget's size doesn't change even though the condition managed to pass through (i.e. , the widget stays the same size but the conditionally rendered components go away) Do you have an intuition as to what is happening

Comment: What do you mean by "the conditionally rendered components go away?", please post a gif for better understanding

Comment: Hey I've updated the post again! Thanks for the help so far

Comment: You mean to say the items inside the list disappear as soon as you try to reorder right?

Comment: I guess that's the expected behavior as we are passing shouldCollapse: true, right?

Comment: Hmm not quite, that's supposed to be the intended effect since those items inside the list are supposed to be be "gone" when i reorder. However, the unintended effect here is that the size of the widget does not change (It should also collapse similar to the other BigWidgets)

Comment: Is it possible to create a minimal working demo sufficient to reproduce the issue in Dartpad?

Comment: Need to look into the code inside the BigWidget for this

Comment: Hey! Made a minimal working demo and updated the question

Comment: Can you double check the dartpad link? its pointing to counter app

Comment: My bad! Fixed the link sorry for the trouble

Comment: Will look into it in sometime

Comment: It's not changing the size of the widget because it will use itemExtent property and use its previous size instead. Try playing around with itemExtent property

Comment: Hey! Thank you so much for the help. I'll try playing around with the itemExtent. In the meantime, I was thinking of also trying with nested gesture detectors, what do you think? I have ran into some issues trying the alternative method as well, I'll drop a link here if you're interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73876834/dynamically-allow-tap-events-to-propogate-through-widget-tree/73876864#73876864

Comment: I was just thinking through it, actually it's not good to change size of Card when user long presses on it. Think of it from Flutter's rendering perspective, it should also account this for change in the empty space left over as you drag the tile, so in my opinion don't collapse the cards on long press, give a separate arrow button so that users can collapse individual cards if they want to