# Dynamically allow tap events to propogate through widget tree

Tags: flutter

I wish to nest 2 gesture detectors and programmatically and dynamically allow the tap events to pass through each layer.

I have set up the widget tree as demonstrated below

**Structure of the widget tree:**

```
   return GestureDetector(
                onLongPress: (() {
                  print("Outer tap event registered");
                  isDragging.value = true; // <-- this is a value notifier
                }),
                onLongPressUp: (() {
                  isDragging.value = false;
                }),
                child: ValueListenableBuilder(
                    valueListenable: isDragging, // <-- Listening to the isDragging event
                    builder: (context, value, _) {
                      print(value) // <-- This prints as true, so absorbing should be false and the click should propagate through
                      return AbsorbPointer(
                        key: ValueKey(index),
                        absorbing: value == false,
                        child: GestureDetector(
                          onLongPress: (() {
                            print("This should print out!");
                          }),
                          child: FooWidget(),
                        ),
                      );
                    }),
              );
            },
          ),
```

**Expected behavior:**

I expected the output to be:

```
Outer tap event registered
True
This should print out!
```

Since the AbsorbPointer should have been deactivated.

However, this is the result output:

```
Outer tap event registered
True
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be because you can only have one `GestureDetector`.

Try the following code (I've never tested it before, but you can try):

```
ValueListenableBuilder(
                    valueListenable: isDragging, // <-- Listening to the isDragging event
                    builder: (context, value, _) {
                      print(value) // <-- This prints as true, so absorbing should be false and the click should propagate through
                      return AbsorbPointer(
                        key: ValueKey(index),
                        absorbing: value == false,
                        child: GestureDetector(
                          onLongPress: (() {
                            print("This should print out!");
                            print("Outer tap event registered");
                  isDragging.value = true; // <-- this is a value notifier
                          }),
                          onLongPressUp: (() {
                            isDragging.value = false;
                          }),
                          child: FooWidget(),
                        ),
                      );
                    }),
              );
            },
          ),
```

Comment: Is there a round about way to achieve the desired behaviour?

Comment: Hey! I think this solution doesn't get me the desired behaviour, the reason why I need the outer layer for gesture detector is so as to allow more to execute some code, before allowing the click to propagate through to the inner gesture detector

Comment: @neowenshun but I think you can only click the external 'GestureDetector', but not the internal 'GestureDetector', because the external 'GestureDetector' wraps the internal 'GestureDetector'.